# Optimal ordering in Jacobi SVD algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, svd, jacobian

In Jacobi SVD algorithm as given [here](http://www.math.pitt.edu/~sussmanm/2071Spring08/lab09/index.html) every pair of columns of the matrix is orthogonalized until convergence. I want to know that how does the order of selection of the pair of columns affect the convergence of the algorithm.

I am working on implementing this algorithm. In my program even though I am covering every pair of columns but still with a certain order of selection of columns the algorithm doesn't converge even after thousands of iteration. But with ordering like cyclic ordering, the algorithm converges in 10-12 iterations.

The Jacobi rotation of one pair interferes with rotation of another pair. I want to know which order is the best for converging the algorithm in the minimum number of steps.

Comment: Cross-posted also on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239967/optimal-ordering-in-jacobi-svd-algorithm) and [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803457/optimal-ordering-in-jacobi-svd-algorithm) less than a day ago.